# How can I find the source location for a association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

For a regular method I can just call `obj.method(:name).source_location` and that works great, however if I do that for associations the `source_location` points me to `.../activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb` is there anything similar for associations?

I'm working with [Spree](https://spreecommerce.com/) with a bunch of extensions and there are way too many places where it can be defined, I can `grep` my way to it but wondering if there's a straight forward way like `source_location`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that association methods are dynamically generated, IOW, they don't *have* a source location, simply because they don't have "source code"!

Comment: What I was trying to shoot for was the file which defined the association, any extension in spree can add associations so wasn't like opening the model definition and looking at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method [`reflect_on_association`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association) which might help you.

```
Customer.reflect_on_association(:accounts).class_name #=> Account
klass = 'Account'.constantize
klass.method(:my_method).source_location
```

Comment: not quite, the association is probably a `has_one` and is not defined in the other class, but thanks, helpful

Comment: @geermc4 if it's a has_one, then the singularized form of accounts should do, right? ;)

Comment: *probably* a has_one just guessing as I haven't found it, also, the associated class doesn't respond to the method

Comment: Doh, you guys are probably right, this one in particular was just a foreign key on the record /shy